# if a parent element has a chlid then add class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I'm trying to write a script that if a parent element has a chlid then add class onlick, here's what i've got so far. any help would be much appreciated, p.s i know much code is terrible: The parent element is ".pinGrid" and the child is "#pin" and the onclick is "#like"

NOTE: I'm trying to add the class to the child element. The pin boxes are on a for each loop.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#like").click(function () { 
     $('.pinGrid').has( "#pin" ).toggleClass("pincard-checked"); 
   }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pinGridWrapper">
 <div class="pinGrid">

<div class="pin" id="pin1">
  <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
    <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="c1" id="like">
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <p class="pull-left"> </p>
  <!-- date -->
  <h2> Title </h2>
  <!-- title-->
  <p><b>INFO:</b>
    <br>
  </p>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Click</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the parent or the child?

Comment: I'm trying to add the class to the child. sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: `addClass onClick` or `add class on click`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Add class to child element ? May be this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7nogwu4t/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the ID selector to get the child element, then use toggleClass() with the checked status

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.pin').toggleClass("pincard-checked", this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.pincard-checked {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.pin {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pinGridWrapper">
  <div class="pinGrid">
    <div class="pin">
      <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
        <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="c1">
        <label></label>
      </div>
      <p class="pull-left"></p>
      <!-- date -->
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <!-- title-->
      <p><b>INFO:</b>
        <br>
      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Click</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pin">
      <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
        <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="c1">
        <label></label>
      </div>
      <p class="pull-left"></p>
      <!-- date -->
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <!-- title-->
      <p><b>INFO:</b>
        <br>
      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Click</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pin">
      <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
        <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="c1">
        <label></label>
      </div>
      <p class="pull-left"></p>
      <!-- date -->
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <!-- title-->
      <p><b>INFO:</b>
        <br>
      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Click</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kez did you try the demo

Comment: Yes, then i tried integrating it in to my project and it didn't work.

Comment: The pin boxes are on a for each loop, would that make a difference?

Comment: @Kez if it is in a loop, then it is better to use class to select elements since ID of an element must be unique... see the update.. in this case we change the class for the clicked checkbox's parent `pin` element - both `like` and `pin` are now class values not ID

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
var pingrid= $('.pinGrid');
$("#like").click(function () { 
 if(pingrid.hasClass( "#pin" ))
   pingrid.find('#pin').toggleClass("pincard-checked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that, if `.pinGrid` has `#pin`, you want to fire `click()` of `#like`, if thats so,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#like").click(function () { 
     //YOUR ACTION
   }); 


   ($('.pinGrid #pin').length>0)?$("#like").trigger("click"):alert("NOT FOUND");

   //IF YOU WANT TO ADD CLASS
   //($('.pinGrid #pin').length>0)?$("#pin").addClass("pincard-checked"):alert("NOT FOUND");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .my_class {
        color:red;
    }


</style>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#like").click(function () {

            if ($('.pinGrid #pin1').length > 0) {
                $('.pinGrid #pin1').toggleClass("my_class")
            }

        });
    });



</script>

<body>
<div class="pinGridWrapper">
 <div class="pinGrid">

<div class="pin" id="pin1">
  <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
    <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="c1" id="like">
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <p class="pull-left"> </p>
  <!-- date -->
  <h2> Title </h2>
  <!-- title-->
  <p><b>INFO:</b>
    <br>
  </p>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Click</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>


</div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

```
$('.pinGrid').has( "#pin" ).toggleClass("pincard-checked");
```

with

```
$('.pinGrid').find( ".pin" ).toggleClass("pincard-checked");
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ac3swjo0/)